# Python code only working for title tag not for table

Tags: python, python-2.7

In regex when writing `<title>(.+?)</title>` it is working but when this title tag is change to `<table>(.+?)</table>` it gives '[]' (square brackets) as output.
My code is :

```
import urllib
import re

urls = ["http://physics.iitd.ac.in/content/list-faculty-members", "http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/commdir3/list.php?division=3&deptcode=ME","http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/commdir3/list.php?division=3&deptcode=CE"]
i = 0
regex = '<table>(.+?)</table>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)

while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    tables  = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

    print tables
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import urllib
import re

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

urls = ["http://physics.iitd.ac.in/content/list-faculty-members", 
        "http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/commdir3/list.php?division=3&deptcode=ME", 
        "http://www.iitkgp.ac.in/commdir3/list.php?division=3&deptcode=CE"]
i = 0

while i < len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    soup = bs(htmltext)
    tables = soup.find_all('table')

    print tables
    i+=1
```

Comment: Thank you it is working perfectly. :) One more question: What if i want the downloaded data from table should be displayed as in table structure only, can that happen?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you need?

Comment: yeah, what i want is the above link consists of professors data in table form and on running this code i get all their details but it cannot be understood by someone who don't know this. So i want if it could be downloaded in the same table format on cmd?

Comment: Although i have posted this as another question with code that i have tried and the code you have helped with. May i send you the link of question? @bernie

Comment: Sure you may. I will answer that one